# Existing Stencil Component in stencil project

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I am having one question in my mind... two months ago I have created a project(chatbot) with stencil.js and published that component by using it in different front end frameworks like Angular and React.

From the last few days, I am working on another stencil project and it turns out that I have to use that same component that I created two months ago.

So here is the question, can I use the existing stencil web component in an entirely new stencil project?

Answer (score 1):

You can import other Stencil web components into a Stencil project. I think the caveat is that they are both under the same version of Stencil (i.e. not 0.x and 1.x).

Comment: You mean pasting "Dist" folder from the needed web component to current stencil project?

Comment: I assumed you had your component published somewhere as a node package and that you would import it as a dependency. If you just have the bundle, then I think you could just include it like you would any other JS resource - but I have no experience there.

Comment: Thank you @G. Tranter for the response. I will consider this as a probable solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `import 'your-other-stencil-project'` works. I came in search of the same but ended up trying by myself.